# Convert QueryDict to key-value pair dictionary

Tags: python, django, list, dictionary, request

I have a `QueryDict` that I get from `request.POST` in this format:

```
<QueryDict: {'name': ['John'], 'urls': ['google.com/\r\nbing.com/\r\naskjeeves.com/'], 'user_email': ['john.smith@gmail.com']}>
```

Why are the values all in lists?

I did `dict(request.POST)`

I got

```
{'name': ['John'], 'urls': ['google.com/\r\nbing.com/\r\naskjeeves.com/'], 'user_email': ['john.smith@gmail.com']}
```

How can I get?:

```
{'name': 'John', 'urls': 'google.com/\r\nbing.com/\r\naskjeeves.com/'`, 'user_email': 'john.smith@gmail.com'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **list comprehension** to get the first entry from the value lists;

```
dd = dict(request.POST)
ddnew = {k:dd[k][0] for k in dd}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this

```
my_dict = dict(request.POST)
my_dict = {k: v[0] for k, v in my_dict.items()}
print(my_dict)
```

Assume for all dictionary values are lists that only has one element.