# it's possible to Convert, QueryDict list values to normal values, but keeping original type as a QueryDict?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a QueryDict like this:

```
<QueryDict: {u'firstValue': ['abc'], u'secondValue': [[]}>
```

It's possible to get this?

```
<QueryDict: {u'firstValue': 'abc', u'secondValue': []}>
```

I checked similar answers like this: [Convert QueryDict to key-value pair dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63925124/convert-querydict-to-key-value-pair-dictionary), but the original type changed. I also tried this:

```
import json
QueryDict(json.dumps(myQueryDict),mutable=True).copy()
```

But, I got:

```
<QueryDict: {u'{"firstValue": "1285", "secondValue": []}': [u'']}>
```

I couldn't find a previous question that keeps the original type. Thanks for any help

Comment: `myQueryDict["firstValue"]` would give you `'abc'` only. What is the problem? It is just how the query dict is represented because parameters names can be repeated.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat myQueryDict receives it's value like this: ```myQueryDict = QueryDict('').copy()``` and then ```myQueryDict.update(anotherQueryDict)```, so that adds [] to all the values. That code send myQueryDict to a method, which expect i.g secondValue as [] but receives [[]] and I must not update that method

Answer (score 0):

saying the "values" variable is the QueryDict

```
values = {u'firstValue': ['abc'], u'secondValue': [[]]}
values_formated = {
    'firstValue': values['firstValue'][0],
    'secondValue': values['secondValue'][0]
    }
```

Basically you are getting an element of the list instead of the whole list.

Comment: values_formated is a dict, so that will changed the original type to a dict, I need to keep the QueryDict